# How to combine multiple text fields into one single IBACTION? - Swift

Tags: function, swift, textfield, ibaction

I'm creating an app that has a lot of textfields that input player names, each one with each own text field, is there a way to combine them all into a single @IBAction? if so, how can I retrieve the text from each one so it can be saved on my plist?

```
    @IBAction func player1NameInput(sender:  UITextField) {


    var nameInput = sender.text


    var playersDictionaryPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PlayersInfo", ofType: "plist")
    var playersDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: playersDictionaryPath!)
    var playersNamesArray = playersDictionary?.objectForKey("playersNames")? as NSMutableArray

    playersNamesArray[0] = "\(nameInput)"

    playersDictionary?.writeToFile(playersDictionaryPath!, atomically: true)

}


@IBAction func player2NameInput(sender: UITextField) {

    var nameInput = sender.text

    var playersDictionaryPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PlayersInfo", ofType: "plist")
    var playersDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: playersDictionaryPath!)
    var playersNamesArray = playersDictionary?.objectForKey("playersNames")? as NSMutableArray

    playersNamesArray[1] = "\(nameInput)"

    playersDictionary?.writeToFile(playersDictionaryPath!, atomically: true)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect all your text fields to the same action. Within that action, determine the index in the names array that you want to use - perhaps you've added all the text fields to an IBOutletCollection and you can get the index from there (if ordering works for them, it didn't for a while). Otherwise, you'd create an array yourself of all the fields. You'd need outlets to them all to do this.